# Angular NgModel does not change if a change from a debounced observable is in-flight

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs

I am messing around with an admittedly weird setup using `ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush` and `RxJS Subject`s with `debounceTime`.

In [this Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/UQmFW0oW0M4NN6ezRrjd?p=preview), I am surprised by the following behaviour:

- Type in the first input box ("Model 1") and verify that it updates the model, and the reset button works
- Type in the second box, and note that the reset button **does not** work if there is already a change in-flight
- Once the 10-second debounced change is finished, the second reset button **does** work as expected

The second reset button deems not to work because instead of immediately updating the value of `model2` in my `ngModelChange` listener, I pass the change event to a `Subject` and debounce it, then only update it after a 10-second debounce. But I am stumped as to why the reset button won't work when an update is in-flight like this. What's going on?

Comment: If you execute `handleReset2()` before the debounceTimer then `this.model2` will have a value of 'Model 2'. So `this.model2 = 'Model 2';` doesn't change anything. I imagine that ngModel keeps a reference to the last known value and does change detection based on that rather than pulling the value from the view to do the comparison.

Comment: It could be something else with change detection but I think this is it. You can see the source code here where it does a comparison to a property named `viewModel`:
https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/79deeacbd7cd53d3e4480ffa292a8755b667d53a/packages/forms/src/directives/ng_model.ts#L182

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This actually happens because the value of `this.model2` hasn't actually changed from `"Model 2"`, even though the value of the input seems to have changed visibly. Because the value being passed into `ngModel` doesn't change, the new value of the input is not overwritten.  The solution here is to maintain the variable model2 updated with the current value:

```
handleChange2(value: string) {
   this.model2 = value;
   this.model2Subject.next(value);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for responding, but `this.model2` is updated in the handler for the reset button, and in the subscription to the `Subject`.

Comment: Hi @BenElliott, as far as I see, in the method handleChange2 the variable model2 isn't updated... you only emit a value in your Subject. When you reset, the value of model2 is still 'Model 2'... You understand? I am meaning in the handleChange2 function.

Comment: yes, that's the point :) The value is not updated directly, but is instead debounced by passing it through a `Subject`. There is a subscription to the `Subject` that then updates the value, at line 38. To reproduce the issue I am referring to, try changing the value in the second input, then press the reset button. The reset button will not work until the debounced `Subject` has emitted.

Comment: Yes, and this is correct. Since model2 has no changed the value, angular will not update it's binding when clicking the reset button, so this is the reason why this is the expected behavior. So my question is, if my answer didn't fit your expectations and knowing why this behaves like this, what are you trying to achieve? Thanks.

Comment: 1) Change the value in the second input. 2) Try to click the reset button and note it doesn't work. 3) Wait 10 seconds, for the change you made in step 1 to propagate to the model. 4) The reset button now works. What I am trying to figure out is why the reset button does not work in step 2.